# PHP Bad File Descriptor Error

Tags: php, apache

We've recently upgraded our servers from PHP 5.4.15 to 5.5.1 and have started getting this error in the logs

> Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor

I've tracked it down to this bit a code that opens another small PHP script which uploads a file to S3 in the background.

```
// Grab uploaded file and assign a working name
$fileTemp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$pathToWorkingFile = tempnam($g_TmpDirectory, "TR-");

// Move the file to our working area        
if (move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $pathToWorkingFile) === false)
    throw new Exception("Cannot move file to staging area.", 1011);

// Where the file will end up on S3
$s3Bucket = "test.bucket.com";
$uploadDest = "/uploads/image123.jpg";

// Create process to upload file in background
popen("/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/uploadScript.php $pathToWorkingFile $s3Bucket $uploadDest &", 'r');
```

Comment: We have no idea what the rest of your code looks like... That one snippet seems quite useless...

Comment: I hope that at least `$SOME $ARGUMENTS` are getting treatment from `escapeshellarg()`.

Comment: Possibly a corrupted file system, The testing and fix depends on your OS. fsck is a place to start on linux or scan/check disk on windows

Comment: One thing that jumps out is you try to _read_ from a process that you run in the _background_?

Comment: @Neal, good point.  I added some more code.

Comment: @Sven, Thanks.  The arguments are all being validated/sanitized higher up in the code.

Comment: @JaredD I encourage you to post your solution in the "Answer" box instead.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Thanks, I made that change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that this error was caused by our configuration of OPcache which was enabled during the PHP upgrade process.  When I disable it for command line operations by removing this setting from php.ini everything works fine.

```
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve with `opcache.enable_cli=1`, but for me the underlying problem was wrong permissions on the `/tmp` directory in MacOS.

This is what I did to fix this:

```
sudo rm -Rf /tmp
sudo rm -Rf /private/tmp
sudo mkdir /private/tmp
sudo chown root:wheel /private/tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
sudo ln -s /private/tmp /tmp
```

Comment: thank you for quick solution. but your line 3 may be incorrect? add `/`before `private/tmp/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu your /tmp permissions are off.

Running this fixed it for me when trying to run `php artisan serve` for laravel.

Run:

`chmod 1777 /tmp`

You may need to use `sudo`.

See the original post here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/what-are-correct-permissions-for-tmp-i-unintentionally-set-it-all-public-recu

Answer (score 0):

I got the `Bad file descriptor` in php-cli in Windows because I had the ***Controlled folder access*** setting turned on in Windows Security → Virus & threat protection → Ransomware Protection.

When I was trying to run composer from the command line, it wasn't able to initialise, and gave the error -

```
[ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(): Write of 111 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor
```

Surprisingly, Windows Security's blocked app notification didn't appear at all. But when I manually went to *Allow an app through controlled folder access* → *Add an allowed app* and selected the `php.exe` executable, composer started working.