# 'Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)' while running php artisan server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, terminal

When I run php artisan server I got the error:

```
php artisan serve
```

> Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
>
> Tue Aug 23 15:51:55 2016 (2381): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933882/php-bad-file-descriptor-error

Answer (score 2):

I just give all permissions to the tmp folder in root and issue was solved.